# Vue3 router can not refresh on production

Tags: refresh, router, vuejs3

I have Vue3 application with router. History mode is enabled so I would expect that I will be able to write vue.domain.com/path/to/view to the browser address bar and go to the required page. But as I see router create urls like expected but I can not refresh the page or go directly to another location via address bar. You can see an example here with login page https://vue.tatrytec.eu/ Try refresh and you will see 404 not found error. The whole [repository is on Github](https://github.com/camohub/tatrytec-vue-admin).

Can somebody tell me please what is the solution of this problem?

EDIT
I found solution but I am not sure if this Apache settings are correct. This is the file from apache2/sites-available

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin xxx@xxxx.xx
        
        ServerName vue.tatrytec.eu

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www/vue.tatrytec.eu/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www/vue.tatrytec.eu/access.log combined

        DocumentRoot /var/www/vue.tatrytec.eu/dist
        <Directory "/var/www/vue.tatrytec.eu/dist">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted               
        
                RewriteEngine on
                  RewriteBase /
                  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
                  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
        </Directory>


        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/vue.tatrytec.eu/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/vue.tatrytec.eu/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure your Apache web server so that it routes all requests to your `index.html`. See [example](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations).

Comment: I found it and it works. But I am not sure if I place the code to the right place in apache file. Can you look at it? I made the question edit. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Apache so I can't really say anything regarding your config.